# How to make the normal button look pressed in sencha?

Tags: css, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How to make the normal button look pressed when the user presses it? Also how to make it look normal when another button is clicked? We can do this using segmented button. But how to achieve it using normal button?

Answer (score 3):

In `sencha-touch-debug.css`, check out the css applied for the pressed `confirm button` ..

```
/* line 73, ../themes/stylesheets/sencha-touch/default/_mixins.scss */
.x-button.x-button-confirm.x-button-pressing, .x-button.x-button-confirm.x-button-pressing:after, .x-button.x-button-confirm.x-button-pressed, .x-button.x-button-confirm.x-button-pressed:after, .x-button.x-button-confirm.x-button-active, .x-button.x-button-confirm.x-button-active:after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-confirm.x-button-pressing, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-confirm.x-button-pressing:after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-confirm.x-button-pressed, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-confirm.x-button-pressed:after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-confirm.x-button-active, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-confirm.x-button-active:after, .x-button.x-button-confirm-round.x-button-pressing, .x-button.x-button-confirm-round.x-button-pressing:after, .x-button.x-button-confirm-round.x-button-pressed, .x-button.x-button-confirm-round.x-button-pressed:after, .x-button.x-button-confirm-round.x-button-active, .x-button.x-button-confirm-round.x-button-active:after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-confirm-round.x-button-pressing, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-confirm-round.x-button-pressing:after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-confirm-round.x-button-pressed, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-confirm-round.x-button-pressed:after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-confirm-round.x-button-active, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-confirm-round.x-button-active:after, .x-button.x-button-confirm-small.x-button-pressing, .x-button.x-button-confirm-small.x-button-pressing:after, .x-button.x-button-confirm-small.x-button-pressed, .x-button.x-button-confirm-small.x-button-pressed:after, .x-button.x-button-confirm-small.x-button-active, .x-button.x-button-confirm-small.x-button-active:after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-confirm-small.x-button-pressing, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-confirm-small.x-button-pressing:after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-confirm-small.x-button-pressed, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-confirm-small.x-button-pressed:after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-confirm-small.x-button-active, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-confirm-small.x-button-active:after {
  background-color: #628904;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #3e5702), color-stop(10%, #507003), color-stop(65%, #628904), color-stop(100%, #648c04));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#3e5702, #507003 10%, #628904 65%, #648c04);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#3e5702, #507003 10%, #628904 65%, #648c04);
}
```

You can have this css in your `app.css` file and then apply it to your button by setting the `pressedCls` property.

```
pressedCls: 'x-button-pressed'
```

Comment: This is when user is pressing AND holding the button, not when user clicked it, like segmented button which is mentioned by the question owner. Anyway, +1 for this

Comment: Yes, you can get the css for that specific configuration in sencha-touch-debug.css sdk file also ...

Answer (score 1):

roadRunner's answer is the solution when the user is **pressing and holding** it, while according to what you mention about segmented button, I think you mean **clicking** on button.

If so, to answer your question, I assume that you have 2 `Ext.Button`, `button_1` and `button_2` (with `id` the same as their names)

When you click on `button_1` and want it to seems like pressed:

```
Ext.getCmp('button_1').setCls('x-button-pressing');
```

When you click on `button_2`, do it similarly and change the look of `button_1`:

```
Ext.getCmp(`button_2`).setCls('x-button-pressing');
Ext.getCmp(`button_1`).setCls('');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: OC also wants to know the css behind it to make it look that way. I have provided that css in my answer.

Comment: please have a look at the question again. He wants to know the way to **set CSS class dynamically**, from normal->pressed (actually clicked, not pressed) and vice-versa, not **the look of that CSS** indeed. Your config does not help when he click on his button, and another button to revert its state, unfortunately.

Comment: The `css` part is equally important. Just blankly setting using the `setCls()` won't help. You need to have that p'cular css config which will make it look like that pressed button.

Comment: no I'm afraid you did not understand what I say. First, the question owner asked 2 things: how to make the button `look like pressed when it's CLICKED ("pressed" word in his expression)`, and how to make that button comes to normal when user clicks another. Second, you provided only the CSS properties, not the way to achieve it since `pressedCls` will not work when user clicked on the button, as what I've already told before.

Comment: please also note that, `setCls()` is to set **additional** CSS class beside `baseCls` of that button. I wrote it (on purpose) in order to remove any additional CSS properties (make it looks like pressed before)

Answer (score -1):

Enable toggle should work.
toggleGroup is to group certain buttons in a group.

```
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'button',
                                        id: 'btnId'
                                        enableToggle: true,
                                        text: 'Toggele Button',
                                        toggleGroup: 'accountbuttons'
                                    }
```